# Scheme program to evaluate arithmetic expression

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, evaluation, arithmetic-expressions

I would like to evaluate an arithmetic expression in scheme Operator can be div,mul,sub,add corresponding to /,*,-,+

```
(arith_eval exp)

Above exp can be a scheme number or (operator expr_1 expr_2)

Input : (arith_eval '(add (sub 8 2) 3))
Expected O/p : 9
```

I'm very new to scheme and I dont know how to begin please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

See for example the following page:  http://icem-www.folkwang-hochschule.de/~finnendahl/cm_kurse/doc/schintro/schintro_116.html